# Track & Monitor all clients requests

Tags: apache, http

I am a victim of hacking intrusion (even if I used a CloudProxy).
I need to track all requests (http) of my website users and save them in a txt file; this will help me to find the exploit (probably).

Is this possible?

I use CentOS with cPanel / Apache server.

Comment: Check all your access_log and error_log files. cPanel must have an option to show them, if you can't access the /var/log folder.

Comment: access_log (in httpd folder) is empty.
where can I activate logging ? WHM ?
Edit : The correct path to access log on cpanel is "/usr/local/apache/logs/access_log"

Comment: cPanel must have an option, otherwise you have to set it in your Apache configuration. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/logs.html

Comment: Thank you very much Marco, I will reset & purge current logs then start monitoring all traffic.